# Powershell: Copy-Item wildcard destination path

Tags: powershell, path, copy-item

Trying to copy an updated shortcut to a wildcard path.  The code works when I run it in a test scenario on the local machine:

```
$Source1 = "C:\Temp\Updated Shortcut\MyShortcut.lnk"
$destination1 = "C:\Temp\Users\*\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar\MyShortcut.lnk"
Get-ChildItem -Path $destination1 | ForEach-Object { Copy-Item -Path $Source1 -Destination $_.DirectoryName }
```

But running it against the production target path does not work:

```
$Source1 = "C:\Temp\Updated Shortcut\MyShortcut.lnk"
$destination1 = "U:\Users\*\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar\MyShortcut.lnk"
Get-ChildItem -Path $destination1 | ForEach-Object { Copy-Item -Path $Source1 -Destination $_.DirectoryName }
```

It will also work if I remove the wildcard and use an actual path:

```
$Source1 = "C:\Temp\Updated Shortcut\MyShortcut.lnk"
$destination1 = "U:\Users\JohnSmith\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar\MyShortcut.lnk"
Get-ChildItem -Path $destination1 | ForEach-Object { Copy-Item -Path $Source1 -Destination $_.DirectoryName }
```

The U:\Users folder does contain 1181 folders in there (one for each of the 1181 users), so not sure if that may be an issue too??

Comment: What errors (if any) are you getting when you try to use a wildcard? Have you tried adding -Verbose to Copy-Item to see what is going on?

Comment: I think running the code over a WAN link might have been caused it to hang or make it seem to hang.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just because code can be written on one line or using a pipeline, does not mean that code is easy to debug or maintain.

Break your code down, debug it, add some logging, etc.

```
$Source1 = "C:\Temp\Updated Shortcut\MyShortcut.lnk"
$destination1 = "U:\Users\*\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar\MyShortcut.lnk"
$items = Get-ChildItem -Path $destination1

Write-Verbose "Number of items: $($items.Count)" -Verbose

foreach ($item in $items)
{
    Write-Verbose "Item: $item" -Verbose
    # use -Force here? Does $_ have a DirectoryName property?
    #
    #Copy-Item -Path $Source1 -Destination $_.DirectoryName

    Copy-Item -Path $Source1 -Destination $item -Force -WhatIf
}
```

My guess is that once you start looking into the diagnostics, you will isolate the issues quickly.

Comment: Thanks Kory, I modified my code with your bits.  This time I ran it from a computer closer to the destination server (I was running it from my machine which is over a 100mb WAN link) and it looks to have worked.